# Web Accessibility: Is the form tag required around inputs to be semantic / accessible?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility

Hey a bit of an odd question..

I am building a web app and I want to make use of form inputs but in some cases I feel the form tag bloats the html. I know that a form tag is not required for validation or for the website to work. But in regards to accessibility does the form tag offer any semantic support for those users?

I have a button which will use the data in the input field so there is no use for submitting a form.

Also the tab index won't matter if there is only one input followed by a button..

```
<label>
     Some Label: <input type="text" id="input">
</label>
```

VS

```
<form>
      <label>
           Some Label: <input type="text" id="input">
      </label>
</form>
```

Comment: The only benefit I can think of would be the ability to add `<legend>` tag (and presumably hide it from sighted users). Sounds like that would be a stretch with only one input and one button, but if it weren't clear that the button and input were related, that might help.

Comment: @StephenThomas you bring up a good point. But that begs the question what situations would you require a legend tag for a one input form. A fringe case that should be considered but in most cases is unnecessary.

Comment: Why do you find the `form` tag so "bloating" ? 
Otherwidse, it could help to ask it as a comment to this article [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2435-are-html-form-tags-required-to-display-form-input-controls.htm)

Comment: @Michel Because why should I have to wrap inputs in a form tag when I am not using a form function at all. Extra markup that otherwise has no meaning.. unless of course its for accessibility hence the question. That article is from 2012 and the latest comment which didn't look to have any feedback was from 2014. Ben Nadel is a boss and I will read the article. The title alone may suggest that it may solve my question. But judging by your comment it doesn't. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating a bit on my comment, it's probably fine to omit the `<form>` tag. Since you mention that there is both an `<input>` element and a `<button>` on the page, though, I can think of one *possible* scenario where the `<form>` tag could help. Presumably, sighted users won't have a problem making the connection between the `<input>` and the `<button>`, probably because of the visual layout of the page. If the connection between them is not clear except from the visual layout, however, then users with assistive technology might find the page confusing. In that case, you could make the connection between the elements explicit by wrapping both the `<input>` and the `<button>` in a single `<form>` and giving that form a `<legend>`. The text of the legend could elaborate on or otherwise clarify the connection. Since sighted users wouldn't need the legend, you could hide the legend from them (by positioning it offscreen, e.g. `position: absolute; left: -999999px;`) This seems like a pretty rare edge case, but perhaps it applies in your situation. Otherwise, I can't think of any good reason to include the `<form>`.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you here. I don't own a screen reader so I can't say for sure but having the very next element the button I think would imply that its associated. But you make a very good point.

Answer (score 3):

> But in regards to accessibility does the form tag offer any semantic support for those users?

It could.

If you read one of the techniques for forms in the WCAG
(http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140916/G184), you will see that assistive technologies *might* enable the user to loop back to the very first text in the form to seek instructions when needed.

So if the user had this possibility (although i don't think it has been implemented), it won't find anything if there is no `form` tag.

Comment: Great point. Makes sense. I wonder if there would be another way to address this without the use of a form tag. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Like Stephen said, you can use a `fieldset` with a `legend` tag but it requires two tags instead of one. I really like the idea that an Assistive Technology can know where a form begins and where a form ends.

Answer (score 1):

This is not *required*. You might want to outline your form so it could be easily navigated to, i.e.:

```
<form id="myform" role="form" aria-label="My greatest form">
```

If you do this, then a screen reader user could easily navigate to the form with his/her region navigation keys. And he/she would easily know where the form starts and ends.
I reiterate, this is not required, it's just more comfortable for screen reader users. If, however, you don't want to attract their attention to the form as a whole, let this alone and do not follow this suggestion.

Comment: `role="form"` is not required. A form element already has the `form` role as long as it has an accessible name (e.g. `aria-labelledby` or `aria-label`). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/form_role